# How can I fetch all child elements of a table row and dynamically change data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a table with header content as shown below.

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                       Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Year
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        HalfYear
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Quarter
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Month
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Site
                    </th>
               </tr>
         </thead>
</table>
```

So from the above table I am trying to read all `<th>` tag content/data and replace the content with new data dynamically.

How can I fetch all `<th>` elements content and edit it with new content in jQuery.

Comment: have you already tried something? please show some code and if there is a error someone will help you

Comment: use ajax call and in response apply your code using jquery.append() if you have json then its good to create table dynamiclly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over a collection of selected jQuery object by using its `each` function, e.g.:

```
$('th').each(function (iteration, node) {
    var oldCaption = $(node).text();
    $(node).text(oldCaption + ' renewed');
});
```

See the jQuery docs for more in-deph info about functions used in the example:

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS is something like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("example");
var ths = table.getElementsByTagName("th");
for(var i=0; i<ths.length; i++){
    ths[i].innerHTML = "my value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you beed to access each "th" singularly

you should give each an "ID":

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="date">
                Date
            </th>
            <th id="year">
                Year
            </th>
            <th id="halfyear">
                HalfYear
            </th>
            <th id="quarter">
                Quarter
            </th>
            <th id="month">
                Month
            </th>
            <th id="site">
                Site
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Than you can use this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTableData(name, value){
    document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = value;
}
</script>
```

you use it like this:

```
 changeTableData("date", "my date")
 changeTableData("year", "my year");
```